# How to interact with painted image in JPanel to trigger events

Tags: java, swing, grid, maps, paint

I have a program that reads in a CSV file with certain characters and adds the character to a char array.

```
Short Example : 
          0,0,.
          0,1.*
          1,0,D
          1,1,.
stored as map[.][*]
             [D][.]
```

this forms an array that when read, depending on the character will draw a pixel on screen. For example if a 'D' is read a Dock.png file is Painted  on to a component part of a Jpanel. The following is the main part of how this program runs

portion that creates the Component

```
JPanelMap = new JPanel();
JPanelMap.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));
this.add(JPanelMap,BorderLayout.CENTER);
map = new MapComponent();
map.loadWorld();
map.loadIcons();
JPanelMap.add(map);
```

MapComponet is the class that loads files,creates arrays, and ultimately draws the image, kind of long since it loads images

```
public class MapComponent extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    BufferedImage image;

    Map dataMap;
    Port dataPort;
    FileHandler fileHandler;

    File fileDock;
    File filePier;
    File fileCrane;
    File fileCargoShip;
    File fileContainerShip;
    File fileOilTanker;
    File fileKraken;
    File fileLeviathan;
    File fileSeaSerpent;
    File fileGodzilla;
    File fileLand;
    File fileSea;
    BufferedImage imgDock;
    BufferedImage imgPier;
    BufferedImage imgCrane;
    BufferedImage imgCargoShip;
    BufferedImage imgContainerShip;
    BufferedImage imgOilTanker;
    BufferedImage imgLeviathan;
    BufferedImage imgKraken;
    BufferedImage imgSeaSerpent;
    BufferedImage imgGodzilla;
    BufferedImage imgLand;
    BufferedImage imgSea;

    char drawMap[][];
    private File fileSafe;
    private BufferedImage imgSafe;
    private File fileUnsafe;
    private BufferedImage imgUnsafe;


    public void loadIcons() {
        try {
            fileDock = new File("Dock.bmp");
            imgDock = ImageIO.read(fileDock);


            filePier = new File("Pier.bmp");
            imgPier = ImageIO.read(filePier);
            fileCrane = new File("Crane.bmp");
            imgCrane = ImageIO.read(fileCrane);
            fileCargoShip = new File("CargoShip.bmp");
            imgCargoShip = ImageIO.read(fileCargoShip);
            fileContainerShip = new File("ContainerShip.bmp");
            imgContainerShip = ImageIO.read(fileContainerShip);
            fileOilTanker = new File("OilTanker.bmp");
            imgOilTanker = ImageIO.read(fileOilTanker);
            fileLeviathan = new File("Leviathan.bmp");
            imgLeviathan = ImageIO.read(fileLeviathan);
            fileKraken = new File("Kraken.bmp");
            imgKraken = ImageIO.read(fileKraken);
            fileSeaSerpent = new File("SeaSerpent.bmp");
            imgSeaSerpent = ImageIO.read(fileSeaSerpent);
            fileGodzilla = new File("Godzilla.bmp");
            imgGodzilla = ImageIO.read(fileGodzilla);
            fileLand = new File("Land.png");
            imgLand = ImageIO.read(fileLand);
            fileSea = new File("Sea.png");
            imgSea = ImageIO.read(fileSea);

            fileSafe = new File("SAFE.bmp");
            imgSafe = ImageIO.read(fileSafe);

            fileUnsafe = new File("UNSAFE.bmp");
            imgUnsafe = ImageIO.read(fileUnsafe);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public MapComponent() {
        drawMap =new char[54][36];
    }

    public void paintMap(Graphics g) //determines what image to draw
    {  
        int col;
        int row;
        char symbol;
        BufferedImage symbolImage=null;

        for (row=0;row<36;row++)
        {
            for (col=0;col<54;col++)
            {
                symbol=drawMap[col][row];
                switch (symbol)
                {

                    //SymbolSet is a class that assigns all the chars to there variable name                    

                    case SymbolSet.CARGOSHIP:
                        symbolImage=imgCargoShip;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.CONTAINERSHIP: 
                        symbolImage=imgContainerShip;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.CRANE:
                        symbolImage=imgCrane;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.DOCK: 
                        symbolImage=imgDock;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.GODZILLA: 
                        symbolImage=imgGodzilla;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.KRAKEN: 
                        symbolImage=imgKraken;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.LAND: 
                        symbolImage=imgLand;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.LEVIATHAN: 
                        symbolImage=imgLeviathan;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.OILTANKER: 
                        symbolImage=imgOilTanker;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.PIER: 
                        symbolImage=imgPier;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.SAFE: 
                        symbolImage=imgSafe;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.SEA: 
                        symbolImage=imgSea;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.SEASERPENT: 
                        symbolImage=imgSeaSerpent;
                        break;
                    case SymbolSet.UNSAFE: 
                        symbolImage=imgUnsafe;
                        break; 


                }
                g.drawImage(symbolImage, col * 10, row * 10, this);
            }
        } 
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        System.out.println("Paint Called");       
        paintMap(g);
    }

    public void loadWorld() {

        //dataMap is created to use generate ships,monsters, and create the map

        dataMap = new Map();
        dataPort = new Port();
        dataMap.generateShipArrayList(10);
        dataMap.generateKraken(20);
        dataMap.generateLeviathan(20);
        dataMap.generateSeaSerpent(20);
        dataMap.createMap();
        drawMap = dataMap.getMapArray();
        //dataMap.taskGenerateGodzilla();


    }

}
```

My question is how do i interact with the map. I want to be able to click on a certain image on the map and have a pop up window or some event happen. I implemented a MouseListener on the JPanel that registers clicks,presses, drags, and location of all the actions using  `event.getX() , event.getY()` but i am unsure of how to tie this into interacting with the map that the array paints onto the jframe.What would be the best way to approach this? The icons i want to trigger an event do have a location variable to know where to put on the array.

Comment: There was really no need to add 179 lines of code to describe this problem, since it only needs one or two grid positions and the same number of images.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: sorry about that, was just trying to be clear. Grid Positions, as in a grid layout?

Comment: *"Grid Positions, as in a grid layout?"*  Yep.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to click on a certain image on the map and have a pop up window or some event happen. … What would be the best way to approach this?

A (possibly undecorated) `JButton`.  Add an `ActionListener` and it will respond to both mouse and keyboard input.